# Asp.net MVC partial view detection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view

Bit of a dumb question but is there any way to ascertain if a view is a partial view and not a full view if the _ (underscore) convention is not used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only difference from a View to a PartialView from what we can look at, is that the PartialView has a null **layout** and View instances has a defined **layout**. Comparing wth asp.net WebForms, the view compare's to a aspx page while the partial view is more like an ascx control. Looking more deeply on how partial views will be handled in HTTP level we can see also that when rendering a View headers are sent but this not happens when rendering a partial view.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1796450.aspx/1